# Program runs in Task Scheduler can not get Registry value

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I have a class named 'Helper', which has function 'GetParamValue':

```
public static string GetParamValue(string value)
{
   using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\ProgParams", false))
   {
       return key.GetValue(value) == null ? string.Empty : key.GetValue(value).ToString();
   }
}
```

And the Windows Form App will call that function in its Program.cs like that:

```
var isAutoNamed = Helper.GetParamValue("AutoNamed");
```

When this app runs from Windows Task Scheduler, isAutoNamed is always return exception. When it run out side Windows Task Scheduler, function is worked well.
What I have to do to fix that?

Comment: What exception does it throw?, always try to include enough debugging information.

Comment: Exception is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: at Helper.GetParamValue(String value) in ...\ConfigHelper\Helper.cs:line 17

Comment: Does the user that your scheduled task runs under have registry keys you care about? (Obviously the answer is "no", but you should get to that answer yourself via debugging).

Comment: Okay, well, that is not much of a help as debugging info. Anyways, generally speaking, `OpenSubKey` returns null if the key it opens isn't found. Apparently, Windows Task Schedular runs with different privileges that doesn't have access to the key. Try adding the key to 'HKLM` or tune the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for all, I will try something...

Comment: Does your app have enough access rights to access a registry from task scheduler? Do you target the x64 bit OS? Maybe there `wow6432Node` redirection